# Spinning lug nut

Tags: lug-nut

Any recommendations on how to remove a spinning lug nut so I can replace the stud? Current lug nut was cross threaded. I tried backing out and letting it shear the stud off since it needed replacing anyway. Instead it just stripped the threads is now just spinning

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you get to the lug nut or is it recessed into the wheel? What metal is the wheels made of (ie: aluminum, steel, ??)? What is the year/make/model of the vehicle?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to drill out the stud far enough to break the lug nut off. Replaced the wheel stud and lug nut.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that the stud is a loss, using a hobby grinder, often called a Dremel™ tool, slice on the end a slot to accept a screwdriver. Alternatively use a similar tool to create a square profile that can accept a socket and breaker bar. Once the stud is secure, you should be able to back off the nut and/or shear the stud. Paulster2 has valid considerations with respect to recessed nuts, which will limit your tool options.

Comment: What do you think about drilling it out with a bit roughly the size of the stud?

Comment: @fred_dot_u - I think the issue mainly is the nut is spinning on the stud. It sounds like you are giving direction where the stud is spinning in the hub. I don't think what you are suggesting will help.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, I see that you are correct. The text is clear that the nut is spinning, not the stud. Perhaps this incorrect answer will help in the future someone with a spinning stud problem.

Comment: Sounds good to me!